# Textbox validation in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, textbox

I am trying to validate a textbox to enter only numbers and set maximum and minimum value in wpf.
I want to do it with the dependency logic....
Can anyone help me with some sample code or project for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962.aspx) on binding validation should get you started. The sample code implements almost exactly what you want. And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771717.aspx) is a link to the entire project, in case you want to download it.

Comment: But i really want to get some project to implement these logics to know the working.. can u get me some sample project?

Comment: See the article that I pointed you to. Right there in the article is a link to a *Binding Validation Sample*. I have edited my answer to include that link as well.